# How to add a prefix - suffix to a view title

Tags: theming

I am using Drupal 8. I want to add Prefix and suffix to view title. 
I tired with following code but in result html is not rendering.

```
function Hook_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
$variables['title_prefix'] ='<div class="row heading-section"><div class="col-md-9 el-col-md-middle">
        <div class="row">';
$variables['title_suffix'] ='</div></div></div>';

}
```

Result

```
<div class="row heading-section"><div class="col-md-9 el-col-md-middle"> <div class="row">My Title</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Is your function really called `Hook_preprocess_page_title`? If yes, you will have to replace the `Hook` part by either the name of your theme or the name of the module where you placed the function. Don't forget to clear the caches after you change hook names or add new hooks. This applies to all hook functions btw.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I have already replace Hook  with my theme name

Comment: Ok, just liked to make sure. - See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables `title_prefix` and `title_suffix` will be rendered using Twig, and therefore filtered from markup and potentially harmful code.

If you like to use HTML within Twig variables, you need to use an instance of the Markup class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for page_title.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page_title(array &$variables) {
  $variables['title_prefix']['#markup'] = Markup::create('<div class="row heading-section"><div class="col-md-9 el-col-md-middle"><div class="row">');
  $variables['title_suffix']['#markup'] = Markup::create('</div></div></div>');
}
```

PS.: The above hook would add the markup to all titles. If this really is your intention, consider altering the `page-title.html.twig` template instead.